# Setup version control for Dreamweaver CS3?

Tags: version-control, dreamweaver

I have NEVER used ANY version control system before. I am currently using the check-in-check-out feature of Dreamweaver but I would like to implement some sort of version control system where I can roll back to previous versions. Also it would be great but not required if I could go back like 3 versions, fix a bug, and have that bug fixed for all the later versions. I have no experience with version control, mainly because I never knew about it until I started reading the pragmatic programmer. So I would probably need step by step directions so if there is a tutorial or something I can be pointed to that would be great too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Turtoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) would be a great first step into proper version control system.

Comment: I installed this, plus SubWeaver which is an extension for this so you can use it within dreamweaver. I am not sure how to set it up for my existing site though. I will make that a new question though.

Answer (score 1):

Bazaar have impressed me lately, it's a fairly new scm and not that many 3rd party tools just yet. But if you want the latest and the greatest try it out!

Step by step guide(!) ;

1. [Download](http://bazaar-vcs.org/Download)
2. [Bazaar in five
   minutes](http://doc.bazaar-vcs.org/latest/en/mini-tutorial/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, and want a smooth but powerful Distributed Version Control System, I recommend [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/) through [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/). As a newcomer to version control, I can attest to its robust and nice, detailed interface, where you can smoothly progress from GUI-clicking to command line operations when needed.